# Django allauth does not detect user.is_authenticated

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I just installed the django all-auth module and my problem is that the user session is always `false`. `user.is_authenticated` always gives me `false`.
I sign up and login with my credentials and get redirected to the `REDIRECT_URL`.
If I go to the `accounts/login` page now, I get redirected to the `REDIRECT_URL`, again. This is till I logout using `accounts/logout`. So I am actually logged in, but `user.is_authenticated` is not working. Thankful for any help.

There I have this simple code:

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            Welcome back {{ user.email }}
        {% else %}
            You are not logged in
        {% endif %}
```

Settings.py (allauth settings):

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
#ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = ("none")
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/app/'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: did u extend django user model ?

Comment: No, I did not change the user model

Comment: Try to put is_staff to true, I had a similar issue and I think I fixed with it

Comment: Where do I have to do this `is_staff = true` ?

Comment: You may have to do it from console line. It is and attribute that User objects has. Just to prove take one of the users that you are using and save it like user.is_staff = True

Comment: I just tried it. Still gives me not logged in. It just wont respond to any `user.attribute`

Comment: And what about if you use request.user.is_autehtnicated on the template? Maybe the problem is that you are passing the authentication thought the request

Comment: I tried that, does not work, too. This is the only function I have inside my views.py `def index(request):
 return render_to_response('app/index.html')`

Comment: And if you try to authenticated the user on the view? request.user.is_authenticated()

Comment: cannot run `request.user.is_authenticated()` only without `()`. Still not working :/

Comment: I don't now... do you have the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS needed, the app in your INSTALLED_APP and the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS?

Comment: `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',  
)
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',  
)`

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'app',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
)`

Comment: It seems to be as it has to be. Try to change in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS the order putting second line the first one

Comment: I changed it, not working, still : /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was, I was not using the `render` function, which includes the `requestContext` parameter, I was missing. Now everything works fine. Thanks alot for support.